# Get package temperature of a Raspberry Pi pico using C

Tags: c, pi-pico, temperature

I'm working on a Raspberry Pi pico and I'm using the C pico-sdk. I want to get the temperature of my package so I followed the datasheet of the [rp2040](https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/rp2040/rp2040-datasheet.pdf) (page 565) and I've used the following code :

```
void init_ADC() {
    adc_gpio_init(GPIO_ADC); //26
    adc_gpio_init(GPIO_BATTERY_LEVEL); //29
    adc_init();
    adc_set_round_robin(0);
    adc_set_temp_sensor_enabled(1);
}

uint16_t get_cpu_temp() {
    adc_select_input(ADC_TEMP_SENSOR); // 4
    uint16_t value = adc_read();
    return value;
}
```

So according to the datasheet, my function get_cpu_temp is supposed to get the value of the ADC that will be between 0 and 65535 since it's an uint16. After that I use the following formula :

```
uint16_t res = get_cpu_temp();
float temp = 27.0f - ((res *3.3f/65535.0f)-0.706f)/0.001721.0f;
```

The resulting value of temp is around 413°C which is obviously wrong, I'm expecting a value around 40°C. I looked for the value of res and it's around 810.

Does anyone sees what I'm doing wrong ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your mistake is to use "65535".
Here you suppose that get_cpu_temp() will return a value between 0 and 65535 but the ADC detailed in datasheet RP2040 is a 12 bit ADC so the result will vary between 0 and 4095.
Maybe you get a better explanation here :
https://how2electronics.com/read-temperature-sensor-value-from-raspberry-pi-pico/#Temperature_Sensor_of_Raspberry_Pi_Pico

They say :

> the MicroPython code can scale the ADC values to a 16-bit range.

So their Python code uses a value between 0 and 65535 but maybe your C code should use a maximum of 4095.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! seems like it's working, I'm getting 45°C :)